# Issue inserting record into Oracle database

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

Please check the below code . I have done debug -found no error . Watched value for query which perfectly works alright if I copy and run manually in the database . But While I run the macro -record does not get inserted and also there isn't any error . DB connection is ok -as it showed runtime error for wrong credentials (tested).

```
Sub INSERT()

Dim strConOracle, oConOracle, oRsOracle
Dim StrResult As String
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Query2 As String

Worksheets("Query").Visible = True

    

 Dim hostName, portNo, SERVICE_NAME, usrID, usrPwd As String
 hostName = "******"
 portNo = "****"
 SERVICE_NAME = "***"
 usrID = "*******"
 usrPwd = "*******"


 strDriver = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;"
 strParams = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + hostName 
  + ")(PORT=" + portNo + ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" + SERVICE_NAME + ")));"
 strUser = "User ID=" + usrID + ";Password=" + usrPwd + ";"

 strConOracle = strDriver + strParams + strUser

 Set oConOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set oRsOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 oConOracle.Open strConOracle
  
'Execute Query
'Query1 = Worksheets("Query").Cells(1, 1).Value
'Set oRsOracle = oConOracle.Execute(Query1)

i = 2
Do While Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""

Query2 = Worksheets("Query").Cells(2, 1).Value
'Query3 = Worksheets("Query").Cells(3, 1).Value
'Query2 = Replace(Query2, "YPUT", Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value)
    
j = 1

Do While j < 4

Query2 = Replace(Query2, "XPUT" & j, Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, j).Value)

j = j + 1
Loop

On Error Resume Next
Set oRsOracle = oConOracle.Execute(Query2)
On Error Resume Next


i = i + 1
Loop


'Set oRsOracle = oConOracle.Execute(Query3)
Set oRsOracle = oConOracle.Execute("COMMIT")

'Close Connection
oConOracle.Close
Set oRsOracle = Nothing
Set oConOracle = Nothing

Worksheets("Input").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Worksheets("Query").Visible = False

ThisWorkbook.Save    

MsgBox ("DONE!!!!!!")   

End Sub
```

Comment: How would you know if there is no error with all those `On Error Resume Next` in there? Remove those first

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid , now I got an error that "SQL Command not properly ended"
Still unable to resolve the issue as the SQL works fine when I run it in DB

Comment: You haven't shown the insert statement being executed, but if works when run manually then I'd guess it has a semicolon (`;`) on the end - which would be allowed in most clients as a statement separator (and implicit executor), but not in a call like this which requires a single statement - and therefore no separator. The semicolon is not part of the actual SQL.

Comment: Please take on board the lesson: `On Error Resume Next` = bad, the statement _there isn't any error_ is very incorrect. Troubleshooting and problem solving is part of technology.

Answer (score 0):

Removing semicolon at the end of the SQL solved my case